# clangd does not find `compile_commands.json` automatically

Tags: clangd, nvim-lspconfig, compilation-database

## Setup

I'm using `clangd` through `neovim` with `nvim-lspconfig`.

```lua
require('lspconfig').clangd.setup {
    -- on_attach = keybinds.on_attach,
    cmd = {
        "clangd",
        "--background-index",
        "--suggest-missing-includes",
        -- "--compile-commands-dir=/home/localuser/test/build",
    },
    filetypes = { "c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp" },
}
```

## Problem

`clangd` is not finding project specific includes.

### What it should be doing

According to the documentation: (https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html)

> clangd will look in the parent directories of the files you edit looking for it, and also in subdirectories named build/. For example, if editing `$SRC/gui/window.cpp`, we search in `$SRC/gui/`, `$SRC/gui/build/`, `$SRC/`, `$SRC/build/`, …

I've built the project with cmake flag `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1` and i have `compile_commands.json` in the build directory: `~/test/build/compile_commands.json`

The source file I am editing is `~/test/src/main.cpp`

As per the documentation, `clangd` should find the compilation database from the build folder, as the build folder is in a parent folder of the source file, but it does not.

### What is happening

`clangd` gives errors on includes. I've included the full `~/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log` at the end.

- I can explicitly show `clangd` where the JSON is with the `--compile-commands-dir` flag (commented in first code block), and then it *does* work. However that is a system-wide configuration so I don't want to do that (and according to the documentation I shouldn't have to)
- I can also symlink `./build/compile_commands.json` to `./compile_commands.json`, and then clangd works correctly.

## Logs

I've created a small example. Its basically just a main() function which includes the opencv library (required in CMakeLists.txt)
The project compiles just fine, but clangd complains that `opencv2/opencv.hpp` cannot be found.

Here's the test project directory layout:

```
localadmin@workstation:~/test$ tree
.
├── build
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.16.3
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   └── test.dir
│   │       ├── build.make
│   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │       ├── CXX.includecache
│   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │       ├── depend.internal
│   │       ├── depend.make
│   │       ├── flags.make
│   │       ├── link.txt
│   │       ├── progress.make
│   │       └── src
│   │           └── main.cpp.o
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── compile_commands.json
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── test
├── build.sh
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

And here's the full `lsp.log`:

```
[START][2022-10-24 14:16:22] LSP logging initiated
[INFO][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:662 "Starting RPC client"   { args = { "--background-index", "--suggest-missing-includes" }, cmd = "clangd", extra = { cwd = "/home/localadmin/test" }}
[TRACE][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1283   "LSP[clangd]"   "initialize_params" { capabilities = { callHierarchy = { dynamicRegistration = false }, offsetEncoding = { "utf-8", "utf-16" }, textDocument = { codeAction = { codeActionLiteralSupport = { codeActionKind = { valueSet = { "", "Empty", "QuickFix", "Refactor", "RefactorExtract", "RefactorInline", "RefactorRewrite", "Source", "SourceOrganizeImports", "quickfix", "refactor", "refactor.extract", "refactor.inline", "refactor.rewrite", "source", "source.organizeImports" } } }, dataSupport = true, dynamicRegistration = false, isPreferredSupport = true, resolveSupport = { properties = { "edit" } } }, completion = { completionItem = { commitCharactersSupport = false, deprecatedSupport = false, documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, preselectSupport = false, snippetSupport = false }, completionItemKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 } }, contextSupport = false, dynamicRegistration = false, editsNearCursor = true }, declaration = { linkSupport = true }, definition = { linkSupport = true }, documentHighlight = { dynamicRegistration = false }, documentSymbol = { dynamicRegistration = false, hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport = true, symbolKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 } } }, hover = { contentFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, dynamicRegistration = false }, implementation = { linkSupport = true }, publishDiagnostics = { relatedInformation = true, tagSupport = { valueSet = { 1, 2 } } }, references = { dynamicRegistration = false }, rename = { dynamicRegistration = false, prepareSupport = true }, signatureHelp = { dynamicRegistration = false, signatureInformation = { activeParameterSupport = true, documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, parameterInformation = { labelOffsetSupport = true } } }, synchronization = { didSave = true, dynamicRegistration = false, willSave = false, willSaveWaitUntil = false }, typeDefinition = { linkSupport = true } }, window = { showDocument = { support = false }, showMessage = { messageActionItem = { additionalPropertiesSupport = false } }, workDoneProgress = true }, workspace = { applyEdit = true, configuration = true, symbol = { dynamicRegistration = false, hierarchicalWorkspaceSymbolSupport = true, symbolKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 } } }, workspaceEdit = { resourceOperations = { "rename", "create", "delete" } }, workspaceFolders = true } }, clientInfo = { name = "Neovim", version = "0.8.0" }, initializationOptions = vim.empty_dict(), processId = 377762, rootPath = "/home/localadmin/test", rootUri = "file:///home/localadmin/test", trace = "off", workspaceFolders = { { name = "/home/localadmin/test", uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test" } }}
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:285    "rpc.send"  { id = 1, jsonrpc = "2.0", method = "initialize", params = { capabilities = { callHierarchy = { dynamicRegistration = false }, offsetEncoding = { "utf-8", "utf-16" }, textDocument = { codeAction = { codeActionLiteralSupport = { codeActionKind = { valueSet = { "", "Empty", "QuickFix", "Refactor", "RefactorExtract", "RefactorInline", "RefactorRewrite", "Source", "SourceOrganizeImports", "quickfix", "refactor", "refactor.extract", "refactor.inline", "refactor.rewrite", "source", "source.organizeImports" } } }, dataSupport = true, dynamicRegistration = false, isPreferredSupport = true, resolveSupport = { properties = { "edit" } } }, completion = { completionItem = { commitCharactersSupport = false, deprecatedSupport = false, documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, preselectSupport = false, snippetSupport = false }, completionItemKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 } }, contextSupport = false, dynamicRegistration = false, editsNearCursor = true }, declaration = { linkSupport = true }, definition = { linkSupport = true }, documentHighlight = { dynamicRegistration = false }, documentSymbol = { dynamicRegistration = false, hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport = true, symbolKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 } } }, hover = { contentFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, dynamicRegistration = false }, implementation = { linkSupport = true }, publishDiagnostics = { relatedInformation = true, tagSupport = { valueSet = { 1, 2 } } }, references = { dynamicRegistration = false }, rename = { dynamicRegistration = false, prepareSupport = true }, signatureHelp = { dynamicRegistration = false, signatureInformation = { activeParameterSupport = true, documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, parameterInformation = { labelOffsetSupport = true } } }, synchronization = { didSave = true, dynamicRegistration = false, willSave = false, willSaveWaitUntil = false }, typeDefinition = { linkSupport = true } }, window = { showDocument = { support = false }, showMessage = { messageActionItem = { additionalPropertiesSupport = false } }, workDoneProgress = true }, workspace = { applyEdit = true, configuration = true, symbol = { dynamicRegistration = false, hierarchicalWorkspaceSymbolSupport = true, symbolKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 } } }, workspaceEdit = { resourceOperations = { "rename", "create", "delete" } }, workspaceFolders = true } }, clientInfo = { name = "Neovim", version = "0.8.0" }, initializationOptions = vim.empty_dict(), processId = 377762, rootPath = "/home/localadmin/test", rootUri = "file:///home/localadmin/test", trace = "off", workspaceFolders = { { name = "/home/localadmin/test", uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test" } } }}
[ERROR][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "clangd"    "stderr"    "I[14:16:22.583] clangd version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
I[14:16:22.583] PID: 377766
I[14:16:22.583] Working directory: /home/localadmin/test
I[14:16:22.583] argv[0]: clangd
I[14:16:22.583] argv[1]: --background-index
I[14:16:22.583] argv[2]: --suggest-missing-includes
I[14:16:22.583] Starting LSP over stdin/stdout
I[14:16:22.584] <-- initialize(1)
I[14:16:22.584] --> reply:initialize(1) 0 ms
"
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:388    "rpc.receive"   { id = 1, jsonrpc = "2.0", result = { capabilities = { codeActionProvider = { codeActionKinds = { "quickfix", "refactor", "info" } }, completionProvider = { resolveProvider = false, triggerCharacters = { ".", ">", ":" } }, declarationProvider = true, definitionProvider = true, documentFormattingProvider = true, documentHighlightProvider = true, documentLinkProvider = { resolveProvider = false }, documentOnTypeFormattingProvider = { firstTriggerCharacter = "
", moreTriggerCharacter = {} }, documentRangeFormattingProvider = true, documentSymbolProvider = true, executeCommandProvider = { commands = { "clangd.applyFix", "clangd.applyTweak" } }, hoverProvider = true, referencesProvider = true, renameProvider = { prepareProvider = true }, selectionRangeProvider = true, signatureHelpProvider = { triggerCharacters = { "(", "," } }, textDocumentSync = 2, typeHierarchyProvider = true, workspaceSymbolProvider = true }, offsetEncoding = "utf-8" }}
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:285    "rpc.send"  { jsonrpc = "2.0", method = "initialized", params = vim.empty_dict()}
[INFO][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1343    "LSP[clangd]"   "server_capabilities"   { server_capabilities = { codeActionProvider = { codeActionKinds = { "quickfix", "refactor", "info" } }, completionProvider = { resolveProvider = false, triggerCharacters = { ".", ">", ":" } }, declarationProvider = true, definitionProvider = true, documentFormattingProvider = true, documentHighlightProvider = true, documentLinkProvider = { resolveProvider = false }, documentOnTypeFormattingProvider = { firstTriggerCharacter = "
", moreTriggerCharacter = {} }, documentRangeFormattingProvider = true, documentSymbolProvider = true, executeCommandProvider = { commands = { "clangd.applyFix", "clangd.applyTweak" } }, hoverProvider = true, referencesProvider = true, renameProvider = { prepareProvider = true }, selectionRangeProvider = true, signatureHelpProvider = { triggerCharacters = { "(", "," } }, textDocumentSync = { change = 2, openClose = true, save = { includeText = false }, willSave = false, willSaveWaitUntil = false }, typeHierarchyProvider = true, workspaceSymbolProvider = true }}
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:285    "rpc.send"  { jsonrpc = "2.0", method = "textDocument/didOpen", params = { textDocument = { languageId = "cpp", text = '#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv ) {

 if(argc != 2)
 {
 std::cerr << std::endl << "Usage: ./datacollector";
 std::cerr << " dataset_save_path" << std::endl;
 // std::cerr << " path_to_settings"; 
 // std::cerr << " path_to_ros2bag_1";
 // std::cerr << " (path_to_ros2bag_2 ... path_to_ros2bag_N) " << std::endl;
 return 1;
 }
}
', uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp", version = 0 } }}
[ERROR][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "clangd"    "stderr"    "I[14:16:22.723] <-- initialized
I[14:16:22.723] unhandled notification initialized
I[14:16:22.723] <-- textDocument/didOpen
"
[ERROR][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "clangd"    "stderr"    "I[14:16:22.724] Failed to find compilation database for /home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp
I[14:16:22.724] Updating file /home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp with command clangd fallback
[/home/localadmin/test/src]
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang /home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp -fsyntax-only -resource-dir=/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0
"
[ERROR][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "clangd"    "stderr"    "I[14:16:22.994] --> textDocument/publishDiagnostics
"
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:388    "rpc.receive"   { jsonrpc = "2.0", method = "textDocument/publishDiagnostics", params = { diagnostics = { { code = "pp_file_not_found", message = "'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found", range = { ["end"] = { character = 29, line = 1 }, start = { character = 9, line = 1 } }, relatedInformation = {}, severity = 1, source = "clang" } }, uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp" }}
[TRACE][2022-10-24 14:16:22] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1052   "notification"  "textDocument/publishDiagnostics"   { diagnostics = { { code = "pp_file_not_found", message = "'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found", range = { ["end"] = { character = 29, line = 1 }, start = { character = 9, line = 1 } }, relatedInformation = {}, severity = 1, source = "clang" } }, uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp"}
[TRACE][2022-10-24 14:16:22] ...lsp/handlers.lua:519    "default_handler"   "textDocument/publishDiagnostics"   { ctx = '{
 client_id = 1,
 method = "textDocument/publishDiagnostics"
}', result = { diagnostics = { { code = "pp_file_not_found", message = "'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found", range = { ["end"] = { character = 29, line = 1 }, start = { character = 9, line = 1 } }, relatedInformation = {}, severity = 1, source = "clang" } }, uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test/src/main.cpp" }}
[INFO][2022-10-24 14:16:29] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1814    "exit_handler"  { { _on_attach = <function 1>, attached_buffers = { true }, cancel_request = <function 2>, commands = {}, config = { _on_attach = <function 3>, autostart = true, capabilities = { callHierarchy = { dynamicRegistration = false }, offsetEncoding = { "utf-8", "utf-16" }, textDocument = { codeAction = { codeActionLiteralSupport = { codeActionKind = { valueSet = { "", "Empty", "QuickFix", "Refactor", "RefactorExtract", "RefactorInline", "RefactorRewrite", "Source", "SourceOrganizeImports", "quickfix", "refactor", "refactor.extract", "refactor.inline", "refactor.rewrite", "source", "source.organizeImports" } } }, dataSupport = true, dynamicRegistration = false, isPreferredSupport = true, resolveSupport = { properties = { "edit" } } }, completion = { completionItem = { commitCharactersSupport = false, deprecatedSupport = false, documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, preselectSupport = false, snippetSupport = false }, completionItemKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 } }, contextSupport = false, dynamicRegistration = false, editsNearCursor = true }, declaration = { linkSupport = true }, definition = { linkSupport = true }, documentHighlight = { dynamicRegistration = false }, documentSymbol = { dynamicRegistration = false, hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport = true, symbolKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 } } }, hover = { contentFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, dynamicRegistration = false }, implementation = { linkSupport = true }, publishDiagnostics = { relatedInformation = true, tagSupport = { valueSet = { 1, 2 } } }, references = { dynamicRegistration = false }, rename = { dynamicRegistration = false, prepareSupport = true }, signatureHelp = { dynamicRegistration = false, signatureInformation = { activeParameterSupport = true, documentationFormat = { "markdown", "plaintext" }, parameterInformation = { labelOffsetSupport = true } } }, synchronization = { didSave = true, dynamicRegistration = false, willSave = false, willSaveWaitUntil = false }, typeDefinition = { linkSupport = true } }, window = { showDocument = { support = false }, showMessage = { messageActionItem = { additionalPropertiesSupport = false } }, workDoneProgress = true }, workspace = { applyEdit = true, configuration = true, symbol = { dynamicRegistration = false, hierarchicalWorkspaceSymbolSupport = true, symbolKind = { valueSet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 } } }, workspaceEdit = { resourceOperations = { "rename", "create", "delete" } }, workspaceFolders = true } }, cmd = { "clangd", "--background-index", "--suggest-missing-includes" }, cmd_cwd = "/home/localadmin/test", filetypes = { "c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp" }, flags = {}, get_language_id = <function 4>, handlers = <1>{}, init_options = vim.empty_dict(), log_level = 2, message_level = 2, name = "clangd", on_attach = <function 5>, on_exit = <function 6>, on_init = <function 7>, root_dir = "/home/localadmin/test", settings = vim.empty_dict(), single_file_support = true, workspace_folders = <2>{ { name = "/home/localadmin/test", uri = "file:///home/localadmin/test" } }, <metatable> = <3>{ __tostring = <function 8> } }, handlers = <table 1>, id = 1, initialized = true, is_stopped = <function 9>, messages = { messages = {}, name = "clangd", progress = {}, status = {} }, name = "clangd", notify = <function 10>, offset_encoding = "utf-8", request = <function 11>, request_sync = <function 12>, requests = {}, rpc = { is_closing = <function 13>, notify = <function 14>, request = <function 15>, terminate = <function 16> }, server_capabilities = { codeActionProvider = { codeActionKinds = { "quickfix", "refactor", "info" } }, completionProvider = { resolveProvider = false, triggerCharacters = { ".", ">", ":" } }, declarationProvider = true, definitionProvider = true, documentFormattingProvider = true, documentHighlightProvider = true, documentLinkProvider = { resolveProvider = false }, documentOnTypeFormattingProvider = { firstTriggerCharacter = "
", moreTriggerCharacter = {} }, documentRangeFormattingProvider = true, documentSymbolProvider = true, executeCommandProvider = { commands = { "clangd.applyFix", "clangd.applyTweak" } }, hoverProvider = true, referencesProvider = true, renameProvider = { prepareProvider = true }, selectionRangeProvider = true, signatureHelpProvider = { triggerCharacters = { "(", "," } }, textDocumentSync = { change = 2, openClose = true, save = { includeText = false }, willSave = false, willSaveWaitUntil = false }, typeHierarchyProvider = true, workspaceSymbolProvider = true }, stop = <function 17>, supports_method = <function 18>, workspaceFolders = <table 2>, workspace_did_change_configuration = <function 19>, workspace_folders = <table 2>, <metatable> = { __index = <function 20> } } }
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:29] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:285    "rpc.send"  { id = 2, jsonrpc = "2.0", method = "shutdown"}
[ERROR][2022-10-24 14:16:30] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "clangd"    "stderr"    "I[14:16:30.000] <-- shutdown(2)
I[14:16:30.000] --> reply:shutdown(2) 0 ms
"
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:30] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:388    "rpc.receive"   { id = 2, jsonrpc = "2.0"}
[DEBUG][2022-10-24 14:16:30] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:285    "rpc.send"  { jsonrpc = "2.0", method = "exit"}
[START][2022-10-24 14:18:47] LSP logging initiated
[INFO][2022-10-24 14:18:47] .../lua/vim/lsp.lua:1814    "exit_handler"  {}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "not reproducible" because the behaviour which you find unexpected is functioning as intended according to the very documentation you quote. You seem to be misunderstanding that documentation. Your source file is test/src/main.cpp. your compile commands db file is test/build/compile_commands.json, which is **NOT** in the same or anestor directory of main.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Given the file /home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/Examples/Stereo-Inertial/stereo_inertial_bag.cc, the places clangd will look are:

```
/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/Examples/Stereo-Inertial/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/Examples/Stereo-Inertial/build/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/Examples/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/Examples/build/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/build/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/compile_commands.json
/home/localuser/Projects/build/compile_commands.json
etc.
```

It does not look at `/home/localuser/SLAM3/MyProject/build` because your source file is not in `MyProject`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in that first code block (fixed). There is no "MyProject" folder.
compile_commands is in `/home/localuser/Projects/SLAM3/build/compile_commands.json`

Comment: @Olli Ok, in that case, I would expect clangd to find it. To try to diagnose the issue further, can you attach complete logs?

Comment: Hi, I've attached the full lsp logs to my original question, along with a simplified small one-file project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Olli: Here is the issue: `clangd version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1`. This is a very old clangd version (latest version is 15.0.3). The logic to look in `build` subdirectories was added in version 11 or 12 I believe. Newer versions can be obtained from https://github.com/clangd/clangd/releases.